# MySQL slow_log query_time 838:59:59

Tags: mysql

Desde hace unos días tengo varias consultas (6 en concreto) en la tabla *slow_log* cuyo valor en el campo *query_time* es 838:59:59. Son consultas simples que se ejecutan rápidamente desde MySQL Workbench y que no tienen bloqueos.

¿Alguien sabe por qué puede ser o si se debe a algún bug? Llevo un par de días buscando y no consigo ver nada. Es una instancia clúster de AWS RDS Aurora, con la versión 5.6.10a de MySQL. Adjunto los datos de las consultas que aparecen:

```
query_time   lock_time  rows_sent  rows_examined  sql_text
'838:59:59'  '00:00:00'   '0'        '0'         'SET autocommit=0'
'838:59:59'  '00:00:00'   '1'        '0'         'select @@session.tx_read_only'
'838:59:59'  '00:00:00'   '0'        '0'         'commit'
'838:59:59'  '00:00:00'   '1'        '1'         'select * from persona_login where persona_id=7686388'
'838:59:59'  '00:00:00'   '1'        '0'         'select @@session.tx_read_only'
'838:59:59'  '00:00:00'   '1'        '0'         'select @@session.tx_read_only'
```

Muchas gracias.
Un saludo

Comment: Ese valor de 838:59:59 es el límite (signed) de los campos TIME en MySQL. [(enlace)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time.html). No sé con certeza si el contenido de la tabla es acumulado.

Comment: Valdría la pena revisar el valor para los parámetros `long_query_time` y `log_queries_not_using_indexes` [(fuente)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/slow-query-log.html)

Comment: Sí, ya sabía que era el valor límite del tipo time, por lo que que sospechaba que fuese algún bug o algún error. Respecto a los dos parámetros que indican, están sin configurar, supongo que tendrán los valores por defecto. Intentaré confirmar si los tiempos en dicha tabla son acumulados. Muchas gracias.